# Import into mysql based on results from another table

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm looking to import JSON data into a table but I only want to grab the fields based on whats in another table.

Here is my example database:

```
CREATE TABLE `fields` (
`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`fieldname` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`encompassid` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO `fields` (`id`, `fieldname`, `fileid`)
VALUES
(1,'streetaddress','11'),
(2,'city','12');
```

So then based on that mapping (ie, street address is field 11) I want to be able to parse the POSTed JSON and grab those fields and insert them into an different table.

```
CREATE TABLE `testfile` (
`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`streetname` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`city` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=29 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Currently my code returns the correct query except the variables do not have the data from the JSON, they are just a string.

```
$con=mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpassword,$db);
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM fields");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $data[] = $row;
    $items = array();
    $itemsV = array();
        $sfv = '';
    foreach ($data as $obj1) {
        if($sfv != "\$".$obj1['fieldname']." = \$obj2->{'".$obj1['fileid']."'};"){
            $sfv .= "\$".$obj1['fieldname']." = \$obj2->{'".$obj1['fileid']."'};";
        }

        $items[] .= $obj1['fieldname'];
        $itemsV[] .= "\$".$obj1['fieldname'];
    }

}


$string = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data2 = json_decode($string);
foreach ($data2 as $obj2) {

        $values  = implode(',', $itemsV);

        eval("\$sfv;");

        $columns = implode(", ",$items);

        $insert = "REPLACE INTO testfile ($columns) VALUES ($values);";

        echo $insert;

}
```

Here is the sample JSON:

```
{
"serializedExport": null,
"format": 1,
"fields": {
    "2": "100000",
    "3": "4.500",
    "4": "360",
    "5": "760.03",
    "6": "",
    "8": "",
    "9": "",
    "10": "",
    "11": "123 HOPE STREET",
    "12": "Philadelphia",
    "13": "",
    "14": "PA",
    "15": "19119",
    "16": "1",
    "17": ""
 }
}
```

Currently the output look like this: `REPLACE INTO fields_testloan (streetaddress, city) VALUES ($streetaddress,$city);` where I'm expecting `REPLACE INTO fields_testloan (streetaddress, city) VALUES ('123 HOPE STREET','Philadelphia');`

Is this possible to do?

Comment: Don't use variable variables. Anything you can do with that can be done better using an associative array.[

Comment: The `foreach` loop that processes `$data` should be after the `while` loop that fills it in, not inside the loop.

Comment: You're using `$obj2` in the first loop, but it's the loop variable of the second loop.

Comment: Shouldn't you be looping over `$data2->fields`?

Comment: I'm looping through the json in the second part.

Comment: And in the JSON, the fields are in `$data->fields`, not `$data`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When reading the `fields` table, create an associative array that maps from field IDs to variable names.

```
$fields = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $fields[$row['fileid']] = $row['fieldname'];
}
```

Then when processing the JSON, create arrays of field names and values. Use the second argument to `json_decode()` so you get an associative array rather than an object, so you can loop over it with `foreach`.

```
$string = file_get_contenst("php://input");
$data2 = json_decode($string, true);

$colnames = array();
$colvalues = array();
foreach ($data["fields"] as $fieldid => $fieldvalue) {
    if (isset($fields[$fieldid])) {
        $colnames[] = $fields[$fieldid];
        $colvalues[] = "'" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $fieldvalue) . "'";
    }
}

$cols_string = implode(",", $colnames);
$vals_string = implode(",", $colvalues);
$sql = "REPLACE INTO testfile ($cols_string) VALUES ($vals_string)";
```

Comment: This returns all of the fields from the JSON, not just the fields lists in $fields[];

Comment: I added an `if` that checks if the fields is in `fields`.

Comment: That did it.  Thank you!